# How to make a Loaded Dice

Tags: java

I am creating a subclass of this Dice class called Loaded Dice that will make a dice roll loaded and by a certain percent, It would look a bit like;

```
public LoadedDice (int anumSides,int loadVal, double loadPct)
```

but I don't know where to start, I've gotten some ideas to create an `ArrayList` and make it have more of one number then the others and pick randomly from there but there's got to be a cleaner way to do it then that right?

```
public class Dice
{

    // --------------------------------------------
    // Instance Variables
    // --------------------------------------------
    private ArrayList<Die>  dieArray;

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors
    // -----------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Default Constructor creates 2 6 sided dice
     */
    public Dice ()
    {
        dieArray = new ArrayList<Die>();
        dieArray.add(new Die());
        dieArray.add(new Die());
    }

    /**
     * Takes an ArrayList of die objects to use
     */
    public Dice (ArrayList<Die> someDice)
    {
        dieArray.addAll(someDice);
    }

    /**
     * Takes in 1 int (# of dice), which creates that number of 6-sided
     * dice
     */
    public Dice (int numberOfDice)
    {
        dieArray = new ArrayList<Die>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
        {
            dieArray.add(new Die());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes in 2 ints (# of dice, # of sides per die) which creates that
     * number of dice with that number of sides per die
     */
    public Dice (int numberOfDice, int numberOfSides)
    {
        dieArray = new ArrayList<Die>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDice; i++)
        {
            dieArray.add(new Die(numberOfSides));
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Class Methods
    // -------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * ContainsDice: takes 0 parameters, and returns a string value
     * representing all of the dice
     */
    public String ContainsDice ()
    {
        String dieString = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < dieArray.size(); i++)
        {

            dieString += (dieArray.get(i) + " ");
        }
        return dieString;
    }

    /**
     * Roll: takes 0 parameters, and returns an int value that is the sum
     * of all the dice rolled
     */
    public int Roll ()
    {
        int value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dieArray.size(); i++)
        {
            value = value + dieArray.get(i).roll();
        }

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Add: Takes a Die object as an input parameter and adds it to the
     * current Dice
     */
    public void Add (Die newDie)
    {
        dieArray.add(newDie);
    }
}
```

Also all of the Dice class is coming from a die class that I created. If needed I can provide that as well.

Comment: Easiest way, use the Random class to get a value between 0 and 1 and then divide that between your dice results. A fair dice would be (0 - 1/6) --> 1, (1/6 - 2/6) --> 2 etc but you can fiddle with that for your weighting e.g (0 - 0.7) --> 1, (0.7 - 1) --> 2, 3,4,5 & 6 never occure

Comment: One way is to use the uneven division as suggested by Richard.  Another (essentially equivalent) approach is to apply a non-linear function to the random number before applying an even division.  A slightly different approach is to re-roll every Nth instance of an "undesirable" outcome.